# How to solve memory issue when extracting ngram using Countvectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, countvectorizer

I have a corpus of size 300 MB. I have 32-bit windows with 32-bit python version 3.6. How much memory will be needed for this operation? My code is below.

```
a = load_files('D:\Train') # have two sub folders.
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(4,4),binary=True)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(a.data)
```

ERROR:

```
File "D:/spyder/april.py", line 32, in <module>
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(a.data)

File "C:\Users\banu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 839, in fit_transform
self.fixed_vocabulary_)

File "C:\Users\banu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 762, in _count_vocab
for feature in analyze(doc):

File "C:\Users\banu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 241, in <lambda>
tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)

File "C:\Users\banu\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 141, in _word_ngrams
tokens.append(" ".join(original_tokens[i: i + n]))

MemoryError
```

I searched for the solution in google. They proposed the idea of using Hashing vectorizer. But it is mentioned that it does not give the respective tokens and feature names. Count vectorizer will provide the features and indices. Please provide me a solution with Count vectorizer itself.

Comment: I will also suggest to go with HashingVectorizer. CountVectorizer is not made for handling large datasets. Its primarily to analyse on smaller datasets.  Or else you can try on any other pc with more ram and / or switch to 64 bit windows and python.

Comment: On 32-bit Python you likely have a memory limit of 4 or less GB, which could easily be consumed by your `CountVectorizer`

Comment: reduce the ngram size to 1,2 or 1,3

Comment: I had solved the issue by performing the project in windows 8 64-bit platform with 4 GB RAM

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions